# How can we direct a screenreader to emphasize/stress/pronounce words correctly

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I am looking to improve the screenreader experience on a news website.

Specifically, I do my testing through VoiceOver on Mac, where I have encountered the following issue.

Take the following sentence:

> LIVE - Newsworthy Event Occurs

Here we'd want 'LIVE' to rhyme with '*alive*' (lʌɪv/), but VoiceOver reads the word as rhyming with '*give*' (i.e. /lɪv/). In this case - how the word is pronounced has semantic importance, helping the user differentiate between the two words 'live'.

How can we direct screenreaders on how to pronounce a word?

I've done some searching on Google and SO but not found much of relevance on the topic.

Comment: [WAI Pronunciation Overview](https://www.w3.org/WAI/pronunciation/) and its linked document [Specification for Spoken Presentation in HTML (Working Draft Note)](https://www.w3.org/TR/spoken-html/). As a working draft, there may be implementation issues in browsers or screen readers up to and including no implementation at all.

Comment: Good references from @Ouroborus. With the current technology, you generally **don't** want to force a certain pronunciation. If you try to spell something phonetically in hidden text for the screen reader to announce, Braille users will also get that phonetic spelling and it won't feel right. For the time being, users can adjust their screen reader dictionary to pronounce words a certain way. Worst case, the user can read a word letter by letter if what they hear doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the pronunciation of a particular word, and it's probably a bad idea to do so anyway.

Technically, the pronunciation of a word depends on the screen reader and especially on the voice used.

The user can select the voice to use, and has also access to a pronunciation dictionary in order to fix those of particular words if they aren't satisfied with the defaults.

Forcing a particular pronunciation would go against user preferences, and going against user preferences is almost never a good idea, except in very rare circumstances.

You may be tempted to cheat, by making the original text aria-hidden, and replacing it by an off-screen text especially crafted to sound as you wish.
However,

- It will sound exactly as you wish only with the exact particular voice and screen reader you are using (and provided that no dictionary entry for your special word exists), while the pronunciation might be worse than the original with another voice and/or screen reader
- The notion of "sounding right" is subjective, other people may not agree with you; don't forget that, for most languages, there are a lot of different existing regional accents and pronunciations
- Braille users will also read your special word instead of the original one, and they probably won't understand it (they won't think at all about pronouncing it out loud, why would they?)
- Screen reader users will copy/paste your special word, and neither their sighted friends, nor search engines won't understand  either

So this makes at least a few good reasons not do that.

There well exists some specifications to specify explicitly the pronunciation for a word, but it should be reserved for specific cases only.
If you are publishing a language dictionary or an application to learn a foreign language, yes it certainly makes sense. Otherwise, as seen above, it's probably a bad idea.

Anyway, as far as I know, none of the major screen readers support that.
In fact I think they won't ever do. To keep it short and simple, most speech synthesizers nowadays are working with a database of recorded syllables (called phonemes) that are concatenated to form words and sentences. Such a speech synthesizer can't take a specific pronunciation if it's absent from its database, and so, can at best support only partially the full range of the specification (which has to cover all languages in the world). It's much simpler to tell the screen reader that it has to switch language and choose an appropriate voice for that other language, and this one you can already do it today with the lang attribute